# Qt: how to build QML apps for Symbian devices?

Tags: qt, symbian, qt-creator, qml

I am pretty new to Qt and I have just started looking at QML.  There are some sample applications included with the Nokia Qt SDK for Symbian and I have managed to load them into Qt Creator and run them using the QML Viewer application on the desktop.

I would like to try some of the samples out on a device, but I am totally clueless as to how I would go about getting the qml files to run on a device.  Are they first packaged into a sis file and installed or is the folder simply copied over? If so how is the app started on the device?

Having done some googling the only information I seem to be able to find says that the Qt libraries available for Symbian devices at the moment is only 4.6.3 whereas version 4.7.0 is required for QML apps?  Does this mean that I won't be able to run QML apps on a device at the moment? (Device is S60 5th Edition)

Any help or pointers in the right direction for more information would be much appreciated.

Comment: Qt 4.7.0 is available for Symbian (S60 3.2 upwards).

Comment: According to http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/supported-platforms.html it is also available on S60 3.1 :)

Comment: @sabbour: Oops - and I have recently been testing an app on a Nokia E71, so I should really have got that right...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will be wizards with boilerplate code for Symbian and Maemo/MeeGo in the next Qt Creator release. If you can't wait, you would basically have the QML files side-by-side with the executable that loads them via a QDeclarativeView - or alternatively compile them into the executable as resources (using qrc). You might want to try to checkout and build Qt Creator 2.1 or master branch for this if you want to try right now :)

Answer (score 1):

I wrote some tips and instructions on how to start developing QtQuick on Symbian: http://juhaturunen.com/blog/?p=11